# Change xml selector values from java code

Tags: android

I am trying to create a universal image selector for multiple buttons.
Is there an option to change the xml's "android:drawable" resource from java code?

Comment: for which control you want to set drawable resource. e.g. Button or textview

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) for seeting selector by code as:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.focused));
states.addState(new int[] { },
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal));

imageView.setImageDrawable(states);  //YOUR IMAGE HERE
//AND FOR BUTTON
 button.setBackgroundDrawable(states);//FOR BUTTON
```

Comment: imageView? do i need to set up one within my layout?

Comment: yes as your need create dynamically or add an Imageview to Xml layout

Comment: @user1185841 : you can try to search on google how we create a dynamic ImageView in android.if this answer help u in solving your problem then mark it as answer.Thanks friend!!! :)

Comment: needed to add the negative value for each state to make it work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can set button drawable from java like

```
    btnSettings.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```