# Android change my custom button color in java

Tags: android

I have a custom button defined in xml. I want to change it so that the stroke color and gradient colors can be changed at run time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient android:startColor="#330000"
                android:endColor="#000000" android:angle="270" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#aa0000" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient android:endColor="#330000"
                android:startColor="#000000" android:angle="270" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#aa0000" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient android:endColor="#000000"
                android:startColor="#000000" android:angle="270" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#aa0000" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

I know how to get the Drawable with

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_button);
```

and then something like

```
 btnSettings.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

What I can't figure out is how to get the states and then the shape for each state. And then ultimately, modify the shape attributes such as stroke color and gradient colors.

Edit: After researching this for a bit, it looks like I will need to pretty much replace all of this xml code with java. I would like to rephrase my question such that I need to know how to create the selector, complete with three states and different shape characteristics for each state. The answer does not need to show all three states. Once I see how to do one, I can figure out the rest.

Comment: Is this the background of the button? Then change the background drawable of the button from code `setBackgroundResource(int)`.

Comment: Also you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242735/change-xml-selector-values-from-java-code)

Comment: I added some amplifying info to my question. I hope I can get an answer.

Comment: Your selector is a `StateListDrawable`, your shapes are `ShapeDrawable`-s. Check these, whether you can change the desired attributes.

However i would suggest to have different xml-s for the shapes you want, and cast them to drawables in code, and just replace one to an other (changing the whole shape changes the colors). By the way, why isn't the states enough to change these attributes?

Comment: I can't have different drawable xml's for each one. I need to allow the user to set the color of the custom button & shape at run time.