# How to change pressed color to other color of selector dynamically?

Tags: java, android, selector

that's my selector for list:(item_selector.xml)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/orange" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/orange" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/orange" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

that's my row of list(row_item.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/alarm_item_drawer_selector"
    >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView      
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        style="@style/DrawerItemTextStyle"
        android:textColor="@color/text_drawer_item_selector"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to change android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/orange" to other color dynamically. My goal, to make pressed color for each row different. Is it possible to do?

Comment: you may need `setOnItemClickListener` for an item click, inside that code you can change color of the item on selection

Comment: I prefer to change color inside getView
I guess it looks like something:
1. get selector of View
2. change color of pressed state
3. apply it back

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Affect to each item a new StateListDrawable.

```
    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable= new StateListDrawable();
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.anycolor)));
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused}, new ColorDrawable(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.anycolor)));
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_selected}, new ColorDrawable(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.anycolor)));
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {}, new ColorDrawable(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.anycolor)));

    view.setBackgroundDrawable(stateListDrawable);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did in a project of mine was I created a static method that takes any view, and changes its background to one of six different colour selectors I made. The trick here is not trying to change the listview selector, you want to change the background of the parent layout of your listview's layout.

Here's an example:

listview.xml (The actual content of the listview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:text="Text"
    android:padding="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

getView() method in my adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    Holder holder = new Holder();
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, viewGroup, false);
    } else {

        holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.parent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.parent);
    setRandomListViewSelector(holder.parent);
    holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    holder.text.setText(strs.get(i));

    return view;
}
```

Static method that changes the background:

```
public static void setRandomListViewSelector(View parentView) {

        int i = new Random().nextInt(2);

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                parentView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_blue);
                break;

            case 1:
                parentView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_red);
                break;
       }

}
```

list_selector_blue.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

In my example, I just use the Random class to randomly generate a number between 0 and 1. If you'd like more control, you could create a global variable and increment that by 1 so that you have better control over what background colours are set.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it dynamically you will have to do it by code. For that you will have to use onTouchListener since you want to know when you touch and release on your view.

```
    final TextView textView =findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
        {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The above code will change the text color of your textview when you press it. Change `Color.RED` to your desired color

Comment: Thanks Pedro!
but I have a question
Is possible to do it in this way?
1. get selector of View 2. change color of pressed state 3. apply it back

Comment: I thought to change color dynamically in click listener it's not correct solution:(
I'm new in android development and my aim to learn to do it right

Comment: You won't be able to do it on click listener since it doesn't tell you don't when you released your button

Comment: About the first question. That's not the way to do it but check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242735/change-xml-selector-values-from-java-code

Comment: Pedro your last link is nice. I will wait for a while on other answers, and if I won't get better solution I will mark your post as solution

Comment: @user1711993 read `StateListDrawable` docs, dont use any setOnTouchListener, its not the way it should work

Answer (score 0):

Selector tag has type StateListDrawable. Indexing items start at zero. There is a kotlin sample (tested on Android 8.1)

```
val listDrawable = relativeLayout.background as StateListDrawable
val stateDrawable = listDrawable.getStateDrawable(2) as GradientDrawable // android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/orange"
stateDrawable.setColor(0xff00ff00)
// or stateDrawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00")
// or stateDrawable.setColor(Color.GREEN)
```