# How to change the color of Android Navigation Drawer's Selected Row?

Tags: android, android-navigation

I'm using in my application a RecyclerView navigation drawer and I want to change the background of the selected row in my navigation drawer.
my navigation drawer adapter code is

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.Bind;

public class DrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerAdapter.ViewHolder>{
private static final int HEADER_TYPE = 0;
private static final int ROW_TYPE = 1;
private List<DrawerBean> rows;
static OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
private static Context context;
public DrawerAdapter(Context context,List<DrawerBean> rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType==HEADER_TYPE){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view,viewType);
    }else if(viewType==ROW_TYPE){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_row,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view,viewType);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder.viewType == ROW_TYPE){
        DrawerBean drawerBean = rows.get(position - 1);
        holder.text.setText(drawerBean.getTitle());
        holder.icon.setImageResource(drawerBean.getIcon());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return rows.size()+1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position==0)
        return HEADER_TYPE;
    return ROW_TYPE;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    protected int viewType;
    @Bind(R.id.drawer_row_icon)ImageView icon;
    @Bind(R.id.drawer_row_text)TextView text;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, int vType) {
        super(itemView);
        viewType = vType;
        if(viewType==ROW_TYPE){
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mItemClickListener != null) {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view , int position);
}
public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}}
```

I need in this class to change the color of selected row

Comment: You could use a selector for your row items.

Comment: You need to add a background selector  in your layout Item

Comment: @ Raghunandan @wSakly is this the only way?

Comment: You can add selector from code like this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11242875/2764682

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` does not handle selection states like a `ListView`.You need to do it manually inside your ViewHolder. What you need to do is maintain a reference to the selected item inside the adapter and call `view.setSelected(true)` on the layout view of the selected item position.But I suggest that you should use [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) provided by the Design Support Library. It's much easier to set up and handles the cases seen in your code